# How to make CollectionView cell in same order in all devices

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want my collection view with multiple rows and 2 columns in across devices, but all I get here is single column. Correct me where I'm doing the mistake.

Attaching my code Here

```
class DemoViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    private let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets( top: 50.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 50.0, right: 20.0)
// MARK: -
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }
}

// MARK: - CollectionView Datasource and delegate
extension DemoViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DemoCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? DemoCollectionViewCell {
            cell.backgroundColor = .cyan
            return cell
        } else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
    }
    
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let paddingSpace = sectionInsets.left * (itemsPerRow + 1)
    let width = collectionView.frame.width - paddingSpace
    let widthPerItem = width / itemsPerRow
    
    return CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: widthPerItem)
  }
  
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    sectionInsets
  }
  
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    sectionInsets.left
  }
}
```

I have added collection view to UIView. And collections view contains Image view and Label. Image have height and width of 100 x 100.
What I expect is 2 column in single row. And the result is.
[image]

Comment: Please supply a [mcve]. There are too many unknowns in your code to allow someone to test it (for example, what's `bindData`?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you might be missing the `itemsPerRow` variable and its value assignment. You need to define and set the number of items per row based on the desired layout. In your case, you want 2 columns, so `itemsPerRow` should be set to 2. Here's the modified version of your code:

```swift
class DemoViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    private let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 50.0, right: 20.0)
    private let itemsPerRow: CGFloat = 2 // Number of columns
    
    // MARK: -
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }
}

// MARK: - CollectionView Datasource and delegate
extension DemoViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DemoCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? DemoCollectionViewCell {
            cell.backgroundColor = .cyan
            return cell
        } else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let paddingSpace = sectionInsets.left * (itemsPerRow + 1)
        let availableWidth = collectionView.frame.width - paddingSpace
        let widthPerItem = availableWidth / itemsPerRow

        return CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: widthPerItem)
    }
}
```

By adding the `private let itemsPerRow: CGFloat = 2` and using it in the `sizeForItemAt` method, you ensure that your collection view displays two columns across devices. Adjust the `itemsPerRow` value as needed to control the number of columns you want in your collection view.